# Setup type in redux - Property x does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have setup my redux store in Typescript like below. However when i try to fetch the rockets using useSelector in the Home component IDE throws up error at

```
const rockets = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.rocketList.rockets);
```

**Error message - Property 'rockets' does not exist on type 'never'.**

configureStore.tsx

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import rocketsReducer from "./ducks/rockets";

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  rocketList: rocketsReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

rockets.tsx (This follows the ducks pattern for actions, reducers, types in 1 file)

```
import { IAction, IRocket } from "../../Interfaces";
const STOREROCKETS = "storeRockets";

export const storeRockets = (rockets: IAction) => ({
  type: STOREROCKETS,
  payload: rockets,
});

type RocketState = {
  rockets: IRocket[]
}

const initialState: RocketState = {
  rockets: [],
};

export default (state:RocketState = initialState, action: IAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case STOREROCKETS:
      return { ...state, rockets: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Interfaces.ts

```
import { rootReducer } from "./redux/configureStore";

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>

export interface IRockets {
    rockets: IRocket[]
}

export interface IAction {
    type: string
    payload: { type: string, payload: object[] }
}

export interface IRocket {
    id: string
    name: string
    description: string
    success_rate_pct: number
    active: boolean
    first_flight: string
    wikipedia: string
    cost_per_launch: number
    flickr_images: string[]
}
```

Home.tsx

```
import { RootState } from "../Interfaces";

const Home: FC = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<Boolean>(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [showError, setShowError] = useState<Boolean>(false);
  const [errorText, setErrorText] = useState<String>("");
  const rockets = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.rocketList.rockets);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an excessive nesting of objects in the definition for the action type:

```
export interface IAction {
    type: string
    payload: { type: string, payload: object[] }
}
```

and the action creator:

```
export const storeRockets = (rockets: IAction) => ({
  type: STOREROCKETS,
  payload: rockets,
});
```

Let's say that I have an array of rockets:

```
const rockets: IRocket[] = [];
```

I would expect to call the action creator like:

```
storeRockets(rockets);
```

And get a result like:

```
{
  type: "storeRockets",
  payload: [],
}
```

But instead, your types dictate that you have to call it like:

```
storeRockets({
  type: "sometype",
  payload: { 
    type: "otherType",
    payload: rockets 
  }
})
```

And then the action creator adds *another* level of `type`!  So your actual action is:

```
{
  type: "storeRockets",
  payload: {
    type: "sometype",
    payload: {
      type: "otherType",
      payload: [],
    }
  }
}
```

That's the major issue in your code.

---

You should change your action type to this.  It fixes the nesting issue and also uses the specific object type `IRocket` instead of `object`.

```
export interface IAction {
  type: string;
  payload: IRocket[]
}
```

Your action creator should take just the `payload`, not the whole action.  It *returns* an `IAction`.

```
export const storeRockets = (rockets: IRocket[]): IAction => ({
  type: STOREROCKETS,
  payload: rockets
});
```

---

I would recommend that you set an explicit return type on the reducer so that you get errors if you are not returning the expected type, like you were before.

```
export default (state: RocketState = initialState, action: IAction): RocketState => {
```

I would also recommend that you create a `useSelector` hook that already knows the type of your `RootState` so that you don't have to declare it every time.

```
import { createSelectorHook } from "react-redux";

export const useSelector = createSelectorHook<RootState>();
```

Comment: Thanks! The store rockets args was messed up in my case and yeah the return types were missing too.